# A browser that mirrors data?

Tags: browser, encryption, http

I was wondering if anyone knows of a type of service or browser which has the ability to send an encrypted HTTP request to a web server which is blocked to respond to my geolocation?

to mention I can not use fake IP addresses as it is that which is registered in my ISP so faking that will disconnect my Internet.

So I am looking for a mirror tool to make my requests and get the data and put it somewhere where is it not filtered and I make a request to that third party source to get my content.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you Tried a proxy?

Comment: can you expand on that please.

Comment: @user142191: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Comment: There are more than a dozen link is in that article as samples of such service however not even a single one is available for me to browse. All blocked. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly - access blocked websites via a 3rd party site that is not blocked - wouldn't a VPN do what you require? There are reasonably priced vpn services available that are not as likely to be blocked as a browser proxy.